# MongoDB 3.0 release for Cent OS

Tags: mongodb, centos

Can any one tell me when the MongoDB team will release 3.0 production release Also, will it be available for CentOS?

We are shifting our production boxes from RHEL 6 to CentOS and on the MongoDB download page 3.0.0 rc does not show CentOS in the distribution list.

Comment: @MdHaidar please stop making these nonsense edits. Only code should have `code` format, not names like "MongoDB".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present ( meaning as of writing ) there really isn't an actual "official release date" for MongoDB 3.0 or is there "really" an official source for the repository of binary builds for any platform.

Results vary for each distribution, but in this case you are probably best following the [official documentation links](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/) and changing the version in the required "drop-down" to "3.0 (upcoming)" (and again, as of writing). The "repo" location links have been consistently changed over most OS distributions as of the 3.0 pending release. Url's in the documentation likely need "massaging".

Right now the RHEL/CentOS repo for current is here: http://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/7/mongodb-org/testing/x86_64/RPMS/

Following that you can install a "binary build" of the "current release candidate" for your own usage. Failing that then just go for something like: https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-rhel70-3.0.0-rc11.tgz and deploy according to your platform mapping of locations and configurations.

When it's released then it will be released. Contact your local MUG for more info if someone is prepared to give it to you. Otherwise just live with "Soon".

Comment: thanks for response currently we are running 2.6.4 on cent OS so not an issue for now i was curious to know about 3.0 as collection level locking is something I desperately need to use in use case.

Comment: @viren So "collection level locking" as mentioned is available with the "default" mmap.v.1 engine available. Also the the "Wired Tiger" storage engine allows "document level" concurrency to updates. But as stated, this is "not yet a release" ( as of writing ). Therefore you use the "experimental" repositories or nothing. Or at least wait until an official release is made. Which is currently, "when that happens". No spoilers here, at least not from me.